# Как сделать якорь с плавающим отступом сверху?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, menu, scrollbar

При клике на ссылку идет прокрутка страницы к якорю, но на странице плавающее горизонтальное меню(скрывается при прокрутке вверх) + фиксированное. Получается, что если я выставляю отступ только фиксированного меню, при скролле вниз, плавающее меню появляется и закрывает начало контента, при прокрутке вверх все норм, а если я выставляю отступ учитывая и плавающее меню, то при прокрутке вверх остается top слишком большой.

Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке вниз отступ был в 200px, вверх - в 100 px от якоря?
Заранее спасибо!

Для прокрутки использую такой код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var div = $(this).attr('href'),
  top = $(div).offset().top - 100;
    
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1000);
  });
  
});
```

Comment: не помешало бы немного html, чтобы не самому в песочнице выдумывать

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего можно следить за свойством, которое делает шапку плавающей и по ней делать либо -100 либо -200